# How to tell someone that the boss told me to tell them to call the boss?

Tags: personal-pronouns, reported-speech

The situation is my boss said to me to inform Person1 to call the boss.

> He said to me that he wants you to call him.

Is this correct? Or can say like

> He wants you to call me.

I prefer to avoid report speech.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the verb "say" with the proposition "to", you can use the verb "tell", which may work better for this case, although the meaning is similar (read more [here](https://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/say-and-tell.html)).

You can use the following:

1. **He said that he wants you to call him.** (close to your suggested sentence, but "to me" is not the idiomatic use. This is indeed reported speech)
2. **He told me that he wants you to call him.** (he passed a message, not necessarily using these exact words; this is also reported speech)
3. **He told me to tell you to call him.** (This is not reported speech; it is an instruction to give an instruction)
4. **He wants you to call him**. (No telling or saying, so it is not reported speech; you are making a simple statement).